# Readings in Geometry | Writing partials

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

Let $X$ be the vector field on $\mathbb{R^3}$-$(0,0,0)$ defined by $$X=y^2\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}+z\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}-x\frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}$$

and let $F:\mathbb{R^3}$-$(0,0,0)→(0,0,0)$ be the mapping defined by $$F=(u,v,w)$$where $u=xy$, $v=yz$ and $w=xz$.

If $$F_*(X)=A\frac{\partial}{\partial{u}}+B\frac{\partial}{\partial{v}}+C\frac{\partial}{\partial{w}}$$

then find $A,B,C$. Here $F_*$ is the differential of $F$, that it $F_*=dF$.

My approach to this question was writing $\partial{u}=\partial{(xy)}$ and so on. Is there a such thing that $\partial{(xy)}$? When I look up to definitions of partial derivatives I couldn't find anything like to this notation. I guess I cannot apply $d(xy)=xdy+ydx$ to the partials.

I'm so lost...Any advice/solution will be appreciated.

Comment: This is confusing. Is your $F$ simply the constant $...\to(0,0,0)$? or $$F(x,y,z)=(xy,yz,xz)?$$

Answer (score 1):

On one side,

$$dF = {\partial F \over \partial x} dx + {\partial F \over \partial y} dy + {\partial F \over \partial z} dz.$$

On the other,

$$dF = {\partial F \over \partial u} du + {\partial F \over \partial v} dv + {\partial F \over \partial w} dw$$,

and since $$du = {\partial u \over \partial x} dx + {\partial u \over \partial y} dy + {\partial u \over \partial z} dz$$
(and analogous relations exist for $v$ and $w$), subsitute these in the latter expression for dF and then factor out $dx$, $dy$, and $dz$ to get $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It gives me $dF=dx({\partial F \over \partial u}y+{\partial F \over \partial w}z)+dy({\partial F \over \partial u}x+{\partial F \over \partial v}z)+dz({\partial F \over \partial v}y+{\partial F \over \partial w}x)$. Which leads to ${\partial F \over \partial u}y+{\partial F \over \partial w}z=y^2{\partial F \over \partial x}$ and so on. Am I doing this right?